# How to fix CSRF and [Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie] issue with requireSSL="true"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, csrf, secure-coding

I have found issue with `requireSSL="true"` property in unsecured server (without SSL) in 
`web.config` code line in UAT - `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true" />`.

For CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) fix, we are using:

```cs
var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
```

We cannot read secure cookie from unsecure server. So requireSSL property should be false in web.config for unsecure server.

If we make `requireSSL="false"` CSRF fix works fine but all cookie becomes unsecure which generate other issue `[Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie]`.

We have also attached CSRF fix code in which function `PreventCSRF()` is being called by `OnInit(EventArgs e)` event in `Default.aspx.cs` page.

In local we don’t have SSL, `requireSSL="false"` is working fine with CSRF fix but not for `[Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie]`. So fix for both CSRF and `[Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie]` issues depend on each other.

There are 2 Queries-

1. As in UAT, SSL is managed in load balancer level, IIS boxes do not have SSL certs installed in them. Can we read secure cookie using `Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey]`?
2. If we do `requireSSL="false"` then CSRF fix works fine but all cookie becomes unsecure means `[Missing Secure Attribute in Encrypted Session (SSL) Cookie]` issue persist for all cookies.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer to your question but here is what we can try,

To get maximum benefit from a CSRF token, you can pass it with Request.Headers.
Transporting a token with Header is I guess safe approach.

Default.aspx's OnInit is fine but if you have any httpmodule in between you can try for AcquireRequestState() method and get HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["CSRFToken"] and keep one copy of that token in the session to validate (may be you have some other logic to verify)